# Sign of first level differenced variable changes sign in regression

Tags: regression, panel-data, stationarity, unit-root

I have first level differenced an independent variable in order to combat unit root in panel data. My panel data consists of N = 487 and T = 1491.

When comparing the coefficient of the original variable in a fixed effects model (beta = 0.001740 with p < 0.001) to the differenced variable in a fixed effects model my sign changes (beta = -0.002794 with p < 0.05). It this a normal interaction?

Extra question: If i understood correctly the interpretation of the coefficients does not change? So a 1 unit increase still triggers an inrease/decrease in the dependent variable by the reported coefficients?

Kind regards

EDIT: I have 9 total indepent variables which 8 of them have no unit root and the dependent variable also has no unit root.